# Treat Text Stored in a Field as an Array

Tags: mysql

I have a sales table that has a field that stores salesperson IDs in a comma separated list (ex: "1,2,3,4"). I need to join the salesperson table on this field and return one record per salesperson.  The below doesn't work, but this is the concept I want to do.

```
SELECT u.firstname
FROM sales s
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id IN CAST(s.salespersonId as ARRAY)
```

I know that I have done this in other projects, but I can't remember what I did AND I'm having trouble searching on Google...

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Ref: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
SELECT u.firstname
FROM sales s
LEFT JOIN user u ON FIND_IN_SET(u.id, s.salespersonId) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it creating  a temporary table, please check below link for more help, 
https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-mysql